# Are there any other French words that come from Latin dies?

Tags: étymologie, demande-de-mot, latin, lexique

The French word *quotidien* comes from Latin *dies*, *diei*. Are there any other French words that come from this Latin root? The word *jour* is so predominantly used to mean "day", that I'm curious whether there are any other words built from the Latin *dies*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ***di*** used in all weekdays come from *dies* (e.g. *dies dominicus* → *[**di**manche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimanche)*, *lunae dies* → [*lun**di***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lundi)...).

*[**Jour**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jour)* and ***di***urne come indirectly from *dies* too. (*dies* → *[diurnus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/diurnus#la)* → *jorn* → *jour*)

*[Au**jour**d'**hui**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aujourd%E2%80%99hui)* is coming twice from *dies*: *jour* as already written, and *hui* from *[hodie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodie#la)* / *hoc die* (in this day).

*[Mi**di**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/midi)* (noon) and *[méri**die**n](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9ridien)* from *[meridies](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/meridies#la)* (*medius dies*)

*[Circa**dien**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/circadien)* from *circa diem* (about one day).

***[diè](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di%C3%A8te_(politique))***te from *dieta* , *dies*

*[ja**dis**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jadis)* from old French *ja a dis*

[*tan**dis***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tandis) from Latin *tamdiu* (*tam diu*)

Comment: And also "diurne"

Comment: @distic yes indirectly through *diurnus* like *jour*

Comment: Très bonne réponse! Merci.

Comment: I find it especially interesting that jour comes from dies, indirectly.